# Is preceding a function with CALLBACK or WINAPI or PASCAL (in MFC) is absolutely necessary or only for readability purpose?

Tags: mfc, timer, callback, calling-convention, stdcall

In `MFC VC++`, `setTimer` function is setted using a `CALLBACK` procedure. From the [link](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/callbacks/article.php/c10557) I read that

> A function that is marked with __stdcall uses the standard calling
>   convention so named because all Win32 API functions (except the few
>   that take variable arguments) use it.

And from that, this is what I have understand, ALL THE VC++ MFC FUNCTIONS USE `__stdcall` as their calling conversions.

And `CALLBACK` is defined as follows....

```
 #define CALLBACK __stdcall
```

**What I have read:** 
Preceding a function with CALLBACK is used to emphasise that the particular function will be  called automatically whenever necessary(like in this `setTimer` case or `onClick` case in javascript),

**My doubt is** , In MFC VC++ all functions(except the few
that take variable arguments) has a default calling convention of __stdcall. Hence either preceding  or not preceding a function with `CALLBACK` or `WINAPI` or `PASCAL` has a same effect?

Answer (score 0):

**Is it absolutely necessary for the computer?** It depends on the context. [When you mismatch the calling convention](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx?Redirected=true), you could either get lucky because the datatypes on the stack happen to match the requirements of the API, or it could fail miserably when your code is [run on a different architecture like x64](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx?Redirected=true) and crashes every time.

**Is it absolutely necessary for the maintenance programmer?** Yes, it is. You know, the poor person who will have to figure out your non-standard conventions and clever "optimizations." Some day, that poor person might be you.

[The compiler was yelling at you for a reason](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx?Redirected=true) when you tried to subvert the API.